# get response through ajax request

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am passing a ajax request to php page and alert the response.

php file contains below line

```
$sql2 = "INSERT  INTO `post_tags` (`post_id`, `tag`) VALUES (".$mysqli->insert_id.", ".$tag.")";
echo $sql2;
```

I get the alert. But the sql query is wrong because I need to pass $tag as string as tag is a varchar in sql.

So when I replace the php code with

```
$sql2 = "INSERT  INTO `post_tags` (`post_id`, `tag`) VALUES (".$mysqli->insert_id.", '".$tag."')";
echo $sql2;
```

It inserts the data successfully in the table. But I am not getting any data in return. What may be the issue?

And is there some way to debug these kind of issues? i.e to find php errors from front end?

Comment: Which data you are expecting in return?

Comment: I want to return the sql query for know

Comment: Why did you post the first not working query?

Comment: If I use that. I am getting echo result in js alert.

Comment: Then the "problem" is somwhere in the code that you don't show. You probably have something like `if ($result) {... exit();} echo $sql2`. And `$sql2` is only echoed, when the query fails.

Comment: There is something wrong echoing the second sql string. Because when I echo hard coded string like echo "string". It works.

Comment: Sounds like you're getting an error but cannot see it. Check out [How can I get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-can-i-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)